# ASP.NET MVC4 web optimizations doesnt minify or add cache buster on vanilla internet application

Tags: javascript, css, minify, system.web.optimization

I'm looking at using web optimizations to minify and bundle js and css so I spun up a new vanilla mvc4 internet application in visual studio, set RELEASE mode and hit F5.

It doesn't seem to behave the way I was expecting. When I view source I see.

```
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

I was expecting to see a cache buster ?v=kjzshd3289sjhdf98je3l.

Also the scripts and css are not mininfied.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Application_Start()` in Global.asax try this code:

```
#if DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. sure, that works, but I was under the impression this was handled by the build configuration. When I view source, I now see the cache buster but viewing the source its not minified.
http://localhost:49941/Content/css?v=WMr-pvK-ldSbNXHT-cT0d9QF2pqi7sqz_4MtKl04wlw1

Comment: `EnableOptimizations` overrides compilation element in the Web.config, so it is probably set to "debug" anyways. How do you add your files to bundle? Do .js files remain untouched too?

Comment: js is included like this: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 
and is minified

css is rendered like this: @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
and is not minified

Comment: This is how they are rendered. I'm talking about `new Bundle("~/somepath").Include("~/SomePath")`.

Comment: Ah ok. I have not changed the vanilla code from the VS template so it is still that same code in (I cant paste it all here)

public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{.... bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));......}

Comment: How do you expect your CSS to be minified? Because with such declaration it _IS_ minified.